# Is there a maximum length for overtime in Lúcioball?

Tags: overwatch

Today while playing Lúcioball, I had a competitive match with two goalies who seemed to be unbeatable. The match continued into a seemingly endless overtime as neither team could score a goal.

Of course the game did *eventually* end. After 10-15 minutes our team managed to score a goal and win, but I haven't been able to shake the thought of an endless Lúcioball match stuck in Overtime.

**Is there a maximum length for overtime in Lúcioball? Or could a match keep going on forever if neither team scores?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Based on numerous posts ([1](https://us.battle.net/forums/en/overwatch/topic/20758437113), [2](https://us.battle.net/forums/en/overwatch/topic/20758526875), for starters) reporting a bug related to an unreachable ball causing "permanent" overtime, it would ***seem*** that there is no time limit.

**However**, according to [this post](https://us.battle.net/forums/en/overwatch/topic/20758497056), the game automatically ends after 90 minutes of overtime.

> My two friends and I embarked on our, Lucio ball comp placement matches, we met another great group that we are now in contact with, **however during overtime, the ball just dissipated and then it was infinite overtime, we spent an hour and a half, wall riding and boosted jumping for the hopes of all the exp, however the match just automatically ended at an hour and half,** We were hoping to get the exp back, and possible reimbursement for the trauma, and to make up for the night terrors that I have every night of being stuck in a lucio ball match with no ball. It's just Lucio at that point.

Comment: "That's how you get tinnitus."